# How to have multiple types under a generic "super type" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, typing, levels

*[Never mind this question - In light of the feedback, I realize it is poorly phrased and too vague. I do not delete it because the answer could serve others. Thanks!]*

I am looking for a type structure that allows me to put two similar ordered data types under one generic type.

For example, let's assume I have the following ordered types:

```
data Type1 = Type1Level1 | Type1Level2 | Type1Level3 | Type1Level4 deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, Bounded, Enum) 

data Type2 = Type2Level1 | Type2Level2 | Type2Level3 deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, Bounded, Enum)
```

In the spirit, I would like a generic overarching type like:

```
data GenType = Type1 | Type2
```

But of course that won't work.

I happen to have entities that can be related to one of those types:

```
data Entity = Entity {
  entityId :: String,
  entityType :: -- here I want one of the TypeXLevelY (anything "under GenType")
 } deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

But I'd also like those entities to have specific fields depending if they are of type1 or type2 (does this mean I have to make 2 different "entity" data types?). For example, an entity of type1 should have a field "input" but not the entity of type2.

Also, type1 and type2 should be able to share ordering and several functions in common, such that something like this would make sense:

```
testSuccType :: GenType -> GenType -> Bool
testSuccType type1 type2 = (type2 == succ type1)
```

It looks like I'm needing a class here but (1) I'm not sure that's the case and (2) when I tried to use qualified type for Entity, it didn't like it (apparently this kind of qualification is not supported anymore):

```
data GenType a => Entity = Entity {
  entityId :: String,
  entityType :: a
} deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

I hope this is clear enough.
Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: For what purpose? There are a couple ways to implement something like `getNextLevel`, and they have very different semantics. Knowing what you actually intend to do would make it a lot easier to suggest something to solve it.

Comment: I think `succ` already does what you want - it's type is `succ :: Enum a => a -> a` so just change your `getNextLevel :: Enum a -> a -> a` / `getNextLevel = succ` and it should work for both of your types (`Type1` / `Type2`) - no need for that wrapper-type in this case.

Comment: The `getNextLevel` function is just `succ`: you can [eta reduce](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) those functions to `succ`. There's already a type class for that (`Enum`). Could this be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/135815)?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. getNextLevel is not a great example as it's basically succ indeed. Type1Level1 and Type1Level2 have a 1-to-many relationship. So the point is to be able to create functions around that relationship at the GenType level, independently of the subtype type1 or type2. Thank you for all these clarifying questions. I'll update my question some time later to try making things more clear.

Comment: I don't know how to put this in words, but... the design you're describing sounds very, uh, "clunky". Are you *sure* you want all the things you say you want? Is it possible there's an X-Y problem here? Is it possible you're trying to bring OO-style API design to a functional language? I don't know exactly what's going on, but it doesn't seem right. Perhaps it is time to open a fresh question with more high-level details about the domain you're trying to model that gives rise to these requirements, i.e., without trying to describe a solution, but using more concrete descriptions than "entity".

Comment: This still feels pretty vague to me too, and, yes, also rather clunky. I second the notion that this is probably an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It is clunky and vague indeed. I'll think about it more and will start with a fresh question if I manage to get a more precise description of the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I don't fully understand the question, but perhaps I can give some hints anyway.

Probably the data type definition you are looking for is:

```
data GenType = GT1 Type1 | GT2 Type2
```

Or, somewhat idiomatically, you could pun the constructor names with the type of their (only) field:

```
data GenType = Type1 Type1 | Type2 Type2
```

Then you can implement your shared function like this:

```
getNextLevelGenType (GT1 t1) = GT1 (getNextLevelType1 t1)
getNextLevelGenType (GT2 t2) = GT2 (getNextLevelType2 t2)

-- OR

getNextLevelGenType (Type1 t1) = Type1 (getNextLevelType1 t1)
getNextLevelGenType (Type2 t2) = Type2 (getNextLevelType2 t2)
```

Sometimes it makes sense to share method names via a type class, but whether this makes sense depends a lot on details not shared in the question. If it did make sense, it might look like this:

```
class Leveled a where getNextLevel :: a -> a
instance Leveled Type1 where getNextLevel = succ
instance Leveled Type2 where getNextLevel = succ
instance Leveled GenType where
    getNextLevel (Type1 t1) = Type1 (getNextLevel t1)
    getNextLevel (Type2 t2) = Type2 (getNextLevel t2)
```

If you go that route, there is a generic, parameterized sum type that may be worth considering as an alternative to `GenType`, named `Either`. The main reason to avoid considering it is if `GenType`'s constructor names can serve as human-readable documentation of their meaning. (The examples above, where the names indicate the field type and nothing more, are not good human-readable documentation.) A secondary reason would be if you actually want a sum of three or more types, since nested `Either`s get unwieldy.

```
instance (Leveled a, Leveled b) => Leveled (Either a b) where
    getNextLevel (Left a) = Left (getNextLevel a)
    getNextLevel (Right b) = Right (getNextLevel b)

    -- OR, with Data.Bifunctor imported,

    getNextLevel = bimap getNextLevel getNextLevel
```

Comment: you're being of great help once again. Thank you! I tried to clarify my question. Is my intention a bit more clear?